# Ajax page content is submitting form multiple times as many as page loaded

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have website that every page is being loaded using ajax both back to previous page, but the problem am facing now is submitting a form using ajax post. I try cache a form data with ajax and is working very fine except when i back to `index.php` and load same page again it will submit multiple time. And the more i back and load same page again it will submit how many time i loaded it.

What i really mean is, when i click on `Open Page One` from `index page`, and submit a form it will work at first browser reload. But when i use my ajax back button to navigate to `index page` and load that same `Open Page One` without reloading browser, it will submit two times and if i repeat same process again again, it will keep submitting based on how many time i click back and enter the page again.

Please can anyone help me i have also tried making the form id unique but it only work fine for different page `ID`.

*INDEX.PHP*

```
<div id="ShowPageContent">
    <a href="openpage.php?page=1" class="loadwithajax" data-page-link="index.php">Open Page One</a>
    <a href="openpage.php?page=2" class="loadwithajax" data-page-link="index.php">Open Page Two</a>
    <a href="openpage.php?page=3" class="loadwithajax" data-page-link="index.php">Open Page Three</a>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('click', '.loadwithajax', function(e){
       var targetUrl = e.target.href;
       var prevUrl = $(this).attr('data-page-link');       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: targetUrl,
            data: {targetUrl : targetUrl, prevUrl : prevUrl},
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(htmlBlock){
               $('#ShowPageContent').html(htmlBlock);
           }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

*OPENPAGE.PHP*

```
<?php 
 $validateForm = 'validate-form-'.md5($_GET['targetUrl']);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_GET['prevUrl'];?>" class="loadwithajax" data-page-link="">Back To Main Page</a>
<form action="" method="post" class="<?php echo $validateForm;?>">
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<script>
$(function(){
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('submit', '.<?php echo $validateForm;?>', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_appserver('shop', 'update_product.php'),
            data: $(self).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
           }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No offense but I didn't understand anything...

Comment: @Learner Am sorry for that, meant to say that the form is submitting multiple time. Am using ajax to load all my page content.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Every time you load the page you attach an `onsubmit` handler to the `document`. Load it multiple times and it'll have multiple copies of the same handler. Try adding `$(document).off('submit'...` before your `$(document).on('submit'...`

Comment: @ChanMT Hahahahahaha is working, thanks man.

Comment: @ChanMT Can write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens because every time you load the page you attach an `onsubmit` handler to the `document`. Loading that page multiple times and `document` will have multiple copies of the same handler attached to it.

Adding `$(document).off('submit', '.<?php echo $validateForm;?>')` before `$(document).on('submit'...` will remove the previously attached handlers before adding a new one, and will solve your problem.